# What is the difference between libboost_math_c99f.a and libboost_math_c99.a?

Tags: boost

Compiling the Boost Math library 1.44.0 for iOS produces the following libraries files:

- libboost_math_c99.a
- libboost_math_c99f.a
- libboost_math_tr1.a
- libboost_math_tr1f.a

What is the difference between libboost_math_c99.a and libboost_math_c99 **f**.a , and also between libboost_math_tr1.a and libboost_math_tr1 **f**.a ?

Environment:
GCC 4.2.1
Mac OS X 10.6.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binaries with the `f` suffix contain code for `float`.

The ones with no suffix contain code for `double`.

On some platforms you can also build binaries with an `l` suffix; these contain code for `long double`.